# PHP variable is not working in a heredoc when adding a 6th

Tags: php, html, heredoc

I wrote a heredoc three weeks ago that was working great, and until today it used five PHP variables.

Here is the heredoc:

```
   echo <<<itemDetails_HEREDOC
   <img src="$sitePath/images/logo-landing2.png" />
   <form action="$thisFilename" method="post" name="arti-form" id="arti-formId">
      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 140px">OWNER NAME:</label><input type="text" style="width: 300px"
           id="ownerId" name="ownerName" readonly="readonly" value="$theLoggedInUser" /><br />
      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 140px">THE ITEM:</label><input type="text"  style="width: 300px"
          readonly="readonly" id="itemNameId" name="itemName" value="$itemName" /><br />
      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 140px">LINK:</label><input type="text"  style="width: 300px"
          readonly="readonly" id="itemLinkId" name="link" value="$theLinkID" /><br />
      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 140px">ERA:</label><input type="text"  style="width: 70px"
          readonly="readonly" id="itemEraId" name="itemEra" value="$itemEra" /><br />
itemDetails_HEREDOC;
```

There are six (6) PHP variables in the above heredoc. The first one ($sitePath) *does not work*. I just added it today.

For some reason, the server is not replacing '$sitePath' (the first PHP variable in my heredoc) correctly because when the browser receives the above page, an error is generated:

```
  Notice: Undefined variable: sitePath in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arti-facks\showItem.php on line 221
```

Here are the five PHP variables that have been in the heredoc and working fine for three weeks -- they are being correctly replaced with their values *before* the HTML is sent to my browser:

- $thisFilename
- $theLoggedInUser
- $itemName
- $theLinkID
- $itemEra

Just how do I know the above PHP variables are being correctly resolved on the server, with their associated values being put into the heredoc then sent to the browser?

Simple -- I do a 'view page source' and instead of seeing '$thisFilename', or '$itemName', etc. in the HTML code sent by the server --  I instead see their associated values in the above heredoc HTML content.

For example, the page source shows me that '**$thisFilename**' in the heredoc got correctly resolved to "**showItem.php**."

My '$sitePath' is declared in a global include file called "**globals.php**" and in that file, $sitePath is declared like this:

```
  $sitePath = "http://localhost/Arti-facks";
```

And at the top of showItem.php I have had, for the past three weeks, this include statement to pull in **globals.php**:

```
  require_once 'globals.php'; // Variables and statics used throughout
```

So today I added the $sitePath declaration (above) inside of globals.php

To prove that showItem.php is able to 'see' the newly-declared $sitePath I added to globals.php, I echo the variable -- sure enough, showItem.php is 100% able to 'see' my newly-declared $sitePath.

*And yet* -- despite that -- and despite three weeks of using the above heredoc with its *five other* PHP variables --
the heredoc is *not* getting $sitePath.

When I 'view page source' here's what I see for the $sitePath line of the heredoc above:

```
    <img src="/images/logo-landing2.png" />
```

You can see that the $sitePath part before the /images/logo-landing2.png is *blank* or missing.

Why have I, for three solid problem-free weeks, been getting *five* successfully-resolved PHP variables in the above heredoc, yet I add a 6th PHP variable today and it's as if

> "Goodness, your quota for PHP variables in your heredoc there was maxed out at 5. And now we see you're trying to use a 6th PHP variable -- what were you thinking."

Comment: Is this HEREDOC created inside a function, perhaps? In that case, the global `$sitePath` is out of scope.

Comment: @Michael, +1 there, wow -- yes the heredoc is inside a php function.  And the 5 other php variables that have been working fine for 3 weeks are in the function with the heredoc.  I have in the same globals.php file lots of these: class Labels {
    static public $USERNAMELABEL = "Username";  }  and I can use sytax like Labels::$USERNAMELABEL inside php functions with no problem and yet the 'Labels' class is declared right next to my $sitePath, in globals.php at the same *file scope*.  Why is that and how do I make $sitePath visible in a php function then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the HEREDOC is called inside a function, the global variable `$sitePath` is not in scope.  At the top of the function, use the `global` keyword:

```
function yourfunction() {
  global $sitePath;

  // Then build the HEREDOC
}
```

Or use the `$GLOBALS` array inside the HEREDOC:

```
echo <<<itemDetails_HEREDOC
   <img src="{$GLOBALS['sitePath']}/images/logo-landing2.png" />   
   <form action="$thisFilename" method="post" name="arti-form" id="arti-formId">
      ...snip...

itemDetails_HEREDOC;
```

#### Most prefereable: a function parameter

Or preferable above either option, pass the `$sitePath` variable into functions that need it as a parameter.

```
function yourfunction($sitePath) {
  // now $sitePath is in scope without 
  // reaching into the global namespace
}
```

Comment: I declared, inside the function, 'global $sitePath'  (less typing) and BAM it now works -- thank you.  Question -- in the same globals.php where I declare $sitePath at global scope -- I have this also declared: **class Labels { static public $USERNAMELABEL = "Username"; }**   and I don't need to use the 'global' qualifer, inside a function I can use:  **$foo = Labels::$USERNAMELABEL**  and it works fine -- even though Labels::$USERNAMELABELS is at the same global file scope as my $sitePath?

Comment: @wantTheBest To use a global in a function, you always need to use the `global` keyword in each function (or use `$GLOBALS[]` instead, my preference, or modify the function to receive the var as a parameter)

Comment: The `Labels::$USERNAMELABEL` doesn't need `global` because the `Labels::` portion of it defins its scope. Therefore, there is no ambiguity. In fact, `::` is known as the _scope operator_.